# Accuracy decreasing but loss decreasing Keras Sequence classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), 
metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have the above sequence classification model .There are around 14000 classes
The shape of a training example is (50,59) i.e 50 rows and 59 features. Data is divided in batches and the accuracy is good in one batch but the next batch destroys the accuracy.

Comment: `n_outputs = 14000`? :O --- You need to share how you're training and how you're preprocessing your data.

Comment: n_outputs = 14000 yes actually I didnt tried to minimize the classes. I just took the maximum possible classes as the data was too large to process

Comment: How many data points do you have?